# Create a list of variables for using them with commands from .bat

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a problem with some issue.

What I want:

A [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which will scan each directory from the current path, search .sql files in one, *(for example)*, directory, take a list of `.sql` files and write it in one `file.sql`.

I tried to write some code, but don't know how to do it properly.

I have temporary solution, but its hardcoded:

```
@echo off
del object.sql
dir schema\object /b /a-d > object.txt
for /F %%A In (object.txt) DO echo @%%A | tee -a object.sql >nul
echo exit >> object.sql
del object.txt
pause
```

I can make a list of files in specific directory and text in one file, with syntax I want.

For example:

Directory:

```
/object
```

With some files:

```
test_1.sql
...
test_N.sql
```

And some more directories with some files.

After script I wanna have some files with smth like this in:

```
@test_1.sql
...
@test_N.sql
```

Comment: _N. B.:_ There is no `tee` command in Windows CMD...

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your dir structure.. If all files are in a single `dir`

```
@echo off
type nul>object.sql
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.sql /b /a-d') do echo @%%i>>object.sql
echo exit>>object.sql
```

or if you want to search the directory structure:

```
@echo off
type nul>object.sql
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.sql /b /a-d /s') do echo "@%%i">>object.sql
echo exit>>object.sql
```